# Latest Motorola update burns more battery on RAZR phone idle?

Tags: motorola-droid, battery-life, motorola-droid-razr

I had my Droid Razr tuned pretty well to give me 10-12 hours of use without going below 70-80% of battery life. Since the update to 6.12.181.XT912Verizon.en.US (GB 2.3.6), I'm now down to 40% in the same time period.

Cell standby is the big culprit. It's sucking down huge amounts of battery now. My question is this: Is there anything I can do about this short of rolling back to the previous (flawed) update?

Comment: See: [What is *Cell standby* and how can I keep it from eating my battery?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/29447/16575)

Answer (score 1):

Try [Juice Defender](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.latedroid.juicedefender). It has a data toggle widget.